# How to Handle Accept */* in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I have an app that uses Spring Security, and I've found that some (but not all) of our IE 8 users get just a blank page, rather than being forwarded to the login page.  I tracked this down to the Accept header - when this header is passed:

```
Accept: */*
```

Spring Security ignores it, and fails to call the LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy@391a6d52, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Processing */*
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Ignoring
o.s.s.w.u.m.MediaTypeRequestMatcher - Did not match any media types
o.s.s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint - No match found. Using default entry point
```

I was able to add this workaround:

```
http
  .exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                    acceptHeaderRequestMatcher()); 

@Bean
public RequestMatcher acceptHeaderRequestMatcher() {
    return new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Accept", "*/*");
}
```

Which works, but seems like kind of a hack.  Is there a better fix for this, like overriding the ignoredMediaTypes?  Why would that header be ignored by default?